# Interaction of a view and a Bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm working on an application with Java EE, JPA, PrimeFaces, OmniFaces and PostreSQL.

To better explain my problem, I am going to copy the code from my Bean and from the view it manages, then I will expose my need.

I have the following code for a Bean:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

import org.omnifaces.util.Faces;

import com.mitocode.model.Config;
import com.mitocode.model.Contrato;
import com.mitocode.model.Persona;
import com.mitocode.model.Puesto;
import com.mitocode.service.IConfigService;
import com.mitocode.service.IContratoService;
import com.mitocode.service.IPersonaService;
import com.mitocode.service.IPuestoService;
import com.mitocode.util.MensajeManager;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class ContratoFormBean implements Serializable{

@Inject
private Contrato contrato;
@Inject
private Persona persona;
@Inject
private Puesto puesto;
@Inject
private IPuestoService puestoService;
@Inject
private IPersonaService personaService;
@Inject
private IContratoService contratoService;
@Inject
private IConfigService configService;
private List<Persona> lstPersonas;
private List<Puesto> lstPuestos;
private double sueldo;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    this.listarPersonas();
    this.listarPuestos();       
    Contrato cont = (Contrato)Faces.getFlashAttribute("contrato");
    if(cont != null){           
        this.leer(cont);
    }else{
        this.leerSueldoMinimo();
        //this.obtenerSueldo();
    }           
}

public void leer(Contrato cont){
    try {
        contrato = contratoService.listarPorId(cont);
        this.persona = contrato.getPersona();
        this.puesto = contrato.getPuesto();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        MensajeManager.mostrarMensaje("Aviso", e.getMessage(), "ERROR");
    }       
}   

public void leerSueldoMinimo(){
    try{
        InputStream inputStream = ContratoFormBean.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/parametros.properties");
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(inputStream);

        String parametro = properties.getProperty("sueldo_minimo");
        Config conf = configService.leerParametro(parametro);
        double salarioMinimo = conf.getValor() != null ? Double.parseDouble(conf.getValor()) : 0.0;  
        this.contrato.setSalario(salarioMinimo);
    }catch(Exception e){
        MensajeManager.mostrarMensaje("Aviso", e.getMessage(), "ERROR");
    }
}

public void listarPersonas() {
    try {
        lstPersonas = personaService.listar();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        MensajeManager.mostrarMensaje("Aviso", e.getMessage(), "ERROR");
    }
}

public void listarPuestos() {
    try {
        lstPuestos = puestoService.listar();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        MensajeManager.mostrarMensaje("Aviso", e.getMessage(), "ERROR");
    }
}

public void registrar() {
    try {
        contrato.setIdContrato(contratoService.getSiguientePK(persona));
        contrato.setPersona(persona);
        contrato.setPuesto(puesto);
        contratoService.registrar(contrato);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        MensajeManager.mostrarMensaje("Aviso", e.getMessage(), "ERROR");
    }
}

public void obtenerSueldo(){
    Puesto puesto = (Puesto)Faces.getFlashAttribute("puesto");
    System.out.println(puesto.getSalarioBase());
    if(puesto != null){
        this.contrato.setSalario(puesto.getSalarioBase());  
    }else{
        this.contrato.setSalario(0.0);
    }
}

public Contrato getContrato() {
    return contrato;
}

public void setContrato(Contrato contrato) {
    this.contrato = contrato;
}

public Persona getPersona() {
    return persona;
}

public void setPersona(Persona persona) {
    this.persona = persona;
}

public Puesto getPuesto() {
    return puesto;
}

public void setPuesto(Puesto puesto) {
    this.puesto = puesto;
}

public List<Persona> getLstPersonas() {
    return lstPersonas;
}

public void setLstPersonas(List<Persona> lstPersonas) {
    this.lstPersonas = lstPersonas;
}

public List<Puesto> getLstPuestos() {
    return lstPuestos;
}

public void setLstPuestos(List<Puesto> lstPuestos) {
    this.lstPuestos = lstPuestos;
}


}
```

And the following for the view that will manage the Bean:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head></h:head>
<body>
    <ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/plantilla.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="content">
            <p:messages id="msj" showDetail="false" autoUpdate="true"
                globalOnly="true" />
            <h:form>
                <h:panelGrid columns="4">
                    <p:outputLabel value="Persona" style="font-weight: bold;"/>
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="cboPersona" value="#{contratoFormBean.persona}" required="true" requiredMessage="Debe seleccionar una persona"
                    rendered="#{contratoFormBean.contrato.idContrato == 0}"
                    converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="--Seleccione--" itemValue="#{null}"
                        noSelectionOption="true" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{contratoFormBean.lstPersonas}" var="per"
                        itemLabel="#{per.nombreCompleto}" itemValue="#{per}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <p:outputLabel value="#{contratoFormBean.persona.nombreCompleto}"
                    rendered="#{contratoFormBean.contrato.idContrato != 0}" />
                <p:message for="cboPersona" />
                <p:tooltip for="cboPersona" value="Elija una persona para el contrato"/>

                <p:outputLabel value="Puesto" style="font-weight: bold;" />
                <p:selectOneMenu id="cboPuesto" value="#{contratoFormBean.puesto}" 
                    required="true" requiredMessage="Debe seleccionar un puesto de trabajo" 
                    rendered="#{contratoFormBean.contrato.idContrato == 0}"
                    converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter" oncomplete="#{contratoFormBean.obtenerSueldo()}">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="--Seleccione--" itemValue="#{null}"
                        noSelectionOption="true" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{contratoFormBean.lstPuestos}" var="pue"
                        itemLabel="#{pue.nombre}" itemValue="#{pue}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <p:outputLabel value="#{contratoFormBean.puesto.nombre}"
                    rendered="#{contratoFormBean.contrato.idContrato != 0}" />
                <p:message for="cboPuesto" />
                <p:tooltip for="cboPuesto" value="Elija una puesto para la persona"/>

                <p:outputLabel value="Fecha Inicio" style="font-weight: bold;"/>
                <p:calendar id="txtFecha" value="#{contratoFormBean.contrato.fechaInicio}" required="true" requiredMessage="Debe indicar una fecha de inicio de contrato"
                    rendered="#{contratoFormBean.contrato.idContrato == 0}" locale="es" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" mask="99/99/9999"/>
                <p:outputLabel value="#{contratoFormBean.contrato.fechaInicio}"
                    rendered="#{contratoFormBean.contrato.idContrato != 0}" >
                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
                </p:outputLabel>
                <p:message for="txtFecha" />
                <p:tooltip for="txtFecha" value="Elija una fecha de inicio para el contrato"/>

                <p:outputLabel value="Fecha Fin" style="font-weight: bold;"/>
                <p:calendar id="txtFechaFin" value="#{contratoFormBean.contrato.fechaFin}" required="true" requiredMessage="Debe indicar una fecha de fin de contrato"
                    rendered="#{contratoFormBean.contrato.idContrato == 0}" locale="es" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" mask="99/99/9999"/>
                <p:outputLabel value="#{contratoFormBean.contrato.fechaFin}"
                    rendered="#{contratoFormBean.contrato.idContrato != 0}">
                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" style="font-weight: bold;" />
                </p:outputLabel>
                <p:message for="txtFechaFin" />
                <p:tooltip for="txtFechaFin" value="Elija una fecha de finalización para el contrato"/>


                <p:outputLabel value="Salario" style="font-weight: bold;"/>
                <p:spinner id="txtSalario" value="#{contratoFormBean.contrato.salario}" required="true" requiredMessage="El salario es obligatorio"
                    rendered="#{contratoFormBean.contrato.idContrato == 0}" min="#{contratoFormBean.contrato.salario}" validatorMessage="El monto debe ser mayor o igual al salario mínimo"/>
                <p:outputLabel value="#{contratoFormBean.contrato.salario}"
                    rendered="#{contratoFormBean.contrato.idContrato != 0}">
                    <f:convertNumber currencySymbol="$" maxFractionDigits="2"
                        maxIntegerDigits="6" type="currency" />
                </p:outputLabel>
                <p:message for="txtSalario" />
                <p:tooltip for="txtSalario" value="Ingrese un salario"/>

            </h:panelGrid>

            <p:commandButton value="Aceptar" update="@form"
                rendered="#{contratoFormBean.contrato.idContrato eq 0}"
                actionListener="#{contratoFormBean.registrar()}"
                action="contrato?faces-redirect=true" />
            <p:commandButton immediate="true" value="Cancelar" action="contrato?faces-redirect=true"
                rendered="#{contratoFormBean.contrato.idContrato eq 0}"/>
            <p:commandButton value="Aceptar" immediate="true"
                action="contrato?faces-redirect=true"
                rendered="#{contratoFormBean.contrato.idContrato != 0}" />


        </h:form>

    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

What I need is that when you select a "Puesto" in the combobox "cboPuesto", and can find the salary that corresponds to that "puesto", and that it appears as the default value of the spinner with id "txtSalario".

For that I had supported in Faces.getFlashAttribute ("puesto"), with the intention of getting the selected object selected and then through a service layer find the corresponding salary. But the problem is that it always comes in null.

I also opted to use the "oncomplete" event of the cboPuesto to execute the method called "obtenerSueldo()", but I do not get what I need.

I appeal to you, who have more experience to see if anyone can give me a solution.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: TLDR; please create a simplified version of your code. And your tags tags are to broad. The interaction of a view and bean is 'jsf' and not java or jpa or omnifaces (or primefaces)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you just copied and pasted all the code in the both backing bean and xhtml

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="cboPuesto" value="#{contratoFormBean.puesto}"
.... oncomplete="#{contratoFormBean.obtenerSueldo()}">
```

Here you are assigning the selected value to `contratoFormBean.puesto`
but for the method in the backing bean

```
public void obtenerSueldo(){
Puesto puesto = (Puesto)Faces.getFlashAttribute("puesto");
System.out.println(puesto.getSalarioBase());
if(puesto != null){
    this.contrato.setSalario(puesto.getSalarioBase());  
}else{
    this.contrato.setSalario(0.0);
}
```

You are fetching the value from Flash which you never set into it `Faces.getFlashAttribute("puesto")`.
 The field `puesto` will already contain the value selected from the drop down so just remove the getflash and assign call this will work

the final class should be

```
public void obtenerSueldo(){
System.out.println(puesto.getSalarioBase());
if(puesto != null){
    this.contrato.setSalario(puesto.getSalarioBase());  
}else{
    this.contrato.setSalario(0.0);
}
```

}

> General Remark don't create local variables with same name of global variables(fields). They will be pretty confusing.